# How to get :before selector behind its box?

Tags: html, css

How can I get my :before selector behind its box and in front of containing boxes backgrounds? I'm trying to make paper curl effect but I can't get the :before selector where it must go. I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eritifake/WA876/) to illustrate my problem. And here are the codes:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="paper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 960px;   
    background-color: #fff; /* The :before selector seems to hide behind this */
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    word-spacing: 0.05em;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em; 
}
.content {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 160px 10px 10px 120px;
    float: left;
}

.paper {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.paper:before {
    content: "hallo";
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #777;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: -100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

I need to get the :before selector to appear between "content" and "paper" divs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play with `z-index`. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/WA876/2/)** first.

Here is the modify CSS.

```
.content {
width: 700px;
margin: 160px 10px 10px 120px;
float: left;
position:relative; /*Added Line*/
z-index: 1; /*Added Line*/
}

.paper:before {
content: "hallo";
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #777;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
left: -100px;
z-index: -1; /*Added Line*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually I already had the second z-index there. I can't believe I didn't try it myself. I was sure I had tried that. Probably made a typo and moved on or something.

Answer (score 0):

I made an example in the jsfiddle with your elements. See if this is want you want

http://jsfiddle.net/nGx5Q/

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="paper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit...</div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>


body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 960px;   
    background-color: #fff; /* The :before selector seems to hide behind this */
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    word-spacing: 0.05em;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em; 
    position:relative;
}

.content {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 160px 10px 10px 120px;
    float: left;
    background: #e7e7e7;
        position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}

.paper {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.paper:before {
    content: "hallo";
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #777;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: -100px;
    z-index: -1;

}
```

Comment: Also a correct answer. You made it very clear with the extra background color. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Z-index.

Change:

```
.paper:before {
z-index: -1;}
```

To

```
.paper:before {
z-index: 1;}
```

Comment: Actually, I've just re-read the question and I might have this entirely backwards.